# Shorten Long DNS names

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, hosts

Amazon gives us a very long dns names i.e. c-123-123-123-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Is there a way to map this name into a shorter name

i.e. essentially what i want to do is to modify /etc/hosts file,
and map the long name into a short one, i.e.
aws1 c-123-123-123-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com

but because /etc/hosts file only accepts ip address mapping, then I cannot do that.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an elastic IP then you could add it to your server and then stick a short name for that in /etc/hosts - other than that you can do it with a CNAME in DNS, but that would break when you instances name/ip changes (hence me saying use an elastic ip ;-))

Comment: hm there is no elegant way, is there?

Comment: The scalable way is to use elastic ip's and DNS. anything else will become a PITA once you have more than a few instances runnig

Comment: You can put a short TTL in the CNAME, which will make it more effective.

Answer (score 1):

The only effective way to do this is to get your own domain name and put a `CNAME` in that domain pointing at the Amazon instance.